# How to add traces in plotly.express

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, scatter

I am very new to python and plotly.express, and I find it very confusing...

I am trying to use the principle of adding different traces to my figure, using example code shown here https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/, Line Plot Modes, #Create traces.

BUT I get my data from a .CSV file.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly as plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\x.csv")

fig = px.scatter(data, x="Time", y="OD", color="C-source", size="C:A 1 ratio")

fig = px.line(data, x="Time", y="OD", color="C-source")
fig.show()
```

The above lines produces scatter/line plots with the correct data, but the data is mixed together. I have data from 2 different sources marked by a column named "Strain" in my .csv file that I would like the chart to reflect.

Is the traces option a possible way to do it, or is there another way?

[image: figure plotted with px.line]

Answer (score 23):

You can add traces using an Express plot by using `.select_traces()`. Something like:

```py
fig.add_traces(
    list(px.line(...).select_traces())
)
```

Note the need to convert to `list`, since `.select_traces()` returns a generator.

Comment: Some things get changed this way, e.g. Labels.

Comment: But the layout is missed, how can we add the layout?

Comment: @Hamzah @ Mathy use update_layout()

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you probably want the lines with the scatter dots as well on a single plot?

You're setting `fig` to equal `px.scatter()` and then setting (changing) it to equal `px.line()`.  When set to `line`, the scatter plot is overwritten.

You're already importing graph objects so you can use `add_trace` with `go`, something like this:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data["Time"], y=data["OD"], mode='markers', marker=dict(color=data["C-source"], size=data["C:A 1 ratio"])))
```

Depending on how your data is set up, you may need to add each C-source separately doing something like:

```
x=data.query("C-source=='Term'")["Time"], ... , name='Term'`
```

Here's a few references with examples and options you can use to set up your scatter:

[Scatter plot examples](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/)

[Marker styles](https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/)

[Scatter arguments and attributes](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/)

Comment: Is there a way to pass a plotly.express graph instead of an graph_object in fig.add_trace?

Comment: @NamanBansal Sorry for the very late reply, I just saw this but wanted to add my reply in case anyone else is wondering the same thing.  I played around with this quite a bit but was not able to figure out how get it to work.  So, based on my experience, I think it might not be possible.  Hopefully if anyone happens by that does know how to get it working with express graph, they'll reply here to let us know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the apporach stated in [Plotly: How to combine scatter and line plots using Plotly Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124833/plotly-how-to-combine-scatter-and-line-plots-using-plotly-express/69893669#69893669)

```
fig3 = go.Figure(data=fig1.data + fig2.data)
```

or a more convenient and scalable approach:

`fig1.data` and `fig2.data` are common tuples that hold all the info needed for a plot and the `+` just concatenates them.

```
# this will hold all figures until they are combined
all_figures = []

# data_collection: dictionary with Pandas dataframes
 
for df_label in data_collection:

    df = data_collection[df_label]
    fig = px.line(df, x='Date', y=['Value'])
    all_figures.append(fig)

import operator
import functools

# now you can concatenate all the data tuples
# by using the programmatic add operator 
fig3 = go.Figure(data=functools.reduce(operator.add, [_.data for _ in all_figures]))
fig3.show()
```

Comment: Or you can append `fig.data` and then `go.Figure(data=sum(all_figures, ()))`. Or `go.Figure(data=sum((fig.data for fig in figures), ()))` if you need to iterate twice. ^^

Answer (score 1):

thanks for taking the time to help me out. I ended up with two solutions that worked, of which using "facet_col" to divide the plot into two subplots (1 for each strain) was the most simple solution.

https://plotly.com/python/axes/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. this worked for me also where Fig_Set_B is a list of scatter plots

```
# create a tuple of first line plots in first 6 plots from plot set Fig_Set_B` 
fig_combined = go.Figure(data= tuple(Fig_Set_B[x].data[0] for x in range(6)) ) 
fig_combined.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In similar style to @Peque's answer you can use the plotly.express figure's `.data` attribute:

```py
fig.add_traces(
    px.line(df, x='x', y='y').data
)
```

A toy example with data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# load toy data
data = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.scatter(data, x="year", y="pop", color="country")

fig.add_traces(
    px.line(data, x="year", y="pop", color="country").data
)

fig.show()
```

Note that `.add_trace` (without the 's') will **not** work in the toy example: the px.line call builds a tuple of traces.