# Scatter Plot and trendlines for data subsetted on 2 levels

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, plotly, trendline

I have a dataset (dataset at end of question) of 2 Groups (group1, group2) of 4 scatter measurements each (R1,R2,R3,R4).
I want to plot:

- Scatter of each measurement (R1, R2, R3, R4)
- The Trendline of each measurement (R1,R2, R3, R4)
- The Average line for each group (group1, group2)
- Filled colored error area for each average line (average line +- stddev)

Here is what the plot should look like

[image]

As you can see from the plot above, I have successfully plotted it (dataset and working example below); however the code is very long, maybe there is a **simpler way in plotly to do this**? I think that "Error area, trendlines for 2 groups" is something that a lot of people would do.

Code

```py
import pandas as pd
 #model fitting 
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
 #plotting 
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

 #import the data 
df = pd.read_csv("/content/dfs.csv", sep=None)


 #1 Fun: fit the data
def model(df_):
  y = df_["y"].values
  X = df_["x"].values
  mask = ~np.isnan(X) & ~np.isnan(y)
   #eliminate values with nan #! this shouldn't exist in my case ? 
  reg = stats.linregress(X[mask], y[mask])
  return (reg)

 #2 Fun: make average fit and upper lower bounds
def get_average_line (df_, results_ ):
    
  name_ = df_["Group"].iloc[0] 
  r=results_.query("Group == @name_").describe() #This works but is a patch 
  x = df_["x"].unique()
  y=r["m"]["mean"]*x + r["x"]["mean"]
  y_upper = (r["m"]["mean"]+r["m"]["std"]) *x + (r["x"]["mean"]+r["x"]["std"])
  y_lower = (r["m"]["mean"]-r["m"]["std"]) *x + (r["x"]["mean"]-r["x"]["std"])
  average_line = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y":y, "y_upper":y_upper, "y_lower":y_lower})
  return average_line

 #5 plot the upper and lower bound 
def plot_avearge_lines (df_, name_line ="Group", row=1, col=1):
  #Assume a figure is already started
   #name to use in addition for plotting 
  name = " " + df_["Group"].iloc[0]

  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        name='Average' + name, 
        x=df_["x"],
        y=df_["y"],
        mode='lines',
        line=dict(color='rgb(31, 119, 180)'),
        legendgroup=name
    ),
              row=row, col=col)
  
   #uppet bound
  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        name='Upper Bound'+ name ,
        x=df_["x"],
        y=df_['y_upper'],
        mode='lines',
        marker=dict(color="#444"),
        line=dict(width=0),
        showlegend=False,
        legendgroup=name
    ),
              row=row, col=col)
  
   #lower bound - fill = tonexty will make it fill until line before it
  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        name='Lower Bound' + name ,
        x=df_["x"],
        y=df_['y_lower'],
        marker=dict(color="#444"),
        line=dict(width=0),
        mode='lines',
        fillcolor='rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.3)',
        fill='tonexty',
        showlegend=False, 
        legendgroup=name
    ),
              row=row, col=row)
 
 #scatter of each line (R1, R2, R3, R4)
def plot_scatter_and_fit (df_ , color ="name", row=1, col=1):
  for t in px.scatter(df_, x="x", y="y", color=color, title='',  trendline="ols" ).data:
      fig.add_trace(t, row=1, col=1)


##### MAIN ##########
 #1fit the data  
df_grouped_Group_mes = df.groupby(["Group", "Mes"])
results = df_grouped_Group_mes.apply(model).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'fit_results'})
results = pd.concat([results, pd.DataFrame([(reg.intercept, reg.slope, reg.rvalue, reg.pvalue, reg.stderr)  for reg in results["fit_results"]], columns=["x", "m", "r-value", "p-value", "y-std"])], axis=1)
 #2 make average fit and upper lower bounds
df_grouped_Group = df.groupby(["Group"])
avearge_lines = df_grouped_Group.apply(get_average_line, results_=results).reset_index()

 #3 plot a figure with..
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1,
    cols=1,
    shared_xaxes=False,
    vertical_spacing=0.03,
    specs=[[{"type": "scatter"}]], #, {"type": "table"}
)



 #4 scatter of each line (R1, R2, R3, R4)
df_grouped_Group.apply(plot_scatter_and_fit,  color ="name", row=1, col=1)
 
 #5 plot the upper and lower bound
averge_line_grouped_name = avearge_lines.groupby(["Group"])
averge_line_grouped_name.apply(plot_avearge_lines, name_line ="name", row=1, col=1)

 #layout 
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis_title='y',
    xaxis_title ="x",
    title='error area and trendlines for 2 groups of scatters series',
    width=800,
    height=800,
    hovermode="x",
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df["x"]        
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

Dataset

```py
 Group Mes      name     x     y
group1  R1 group1-R1  2.00   3.0
group1  R1 group1-R1 13.00  50.0
group1  R1 group1-R1 25.00  78.0
group1  R1 group1-R1 37.00 130.0
group2  R1 group2-R1  2.00  35.0
group2  R1 group2-R1  6.00  63.0
group2  R1 group2-R1 10.00  93.0
group2  R1 group2-R1 22.00 323.0
group2  R1 group2-R1 34.00 455.0
group1  R2 group1-R2  5.00  16.0
group1  R2 group1-R2 16.00  76.0
group1  R2 group1-R2 28.00 110.0
group1  R2 group1-R2 40.00 153.0
group2  R2 group2-R2  3.00  47.0
group2  R2 group2-R2  7.13  68.0
group2  R2 group2-R2 13.00 111.0
group2  R2 group2-R2 25.00 353.0
group2  R2 group2-R2 37.00 493.0
group1  R3 group1-R3  8.00  45.0
group1  R3 group1-R3 19.00  82.0
group1  R3 group1-R3 31.00 128.0
group2  R3 group2-R3  0.00  12.0
group2  R3 group2-R3  4.00  53.0
group2  R3 group2-R3  8.00  80.0
group2  R3 group2-R3 16.00 121.0
group2  R3 group2-R3 28.00 394.0
group2  R3 group2-R3 40.00 521.0
group1  R4 group1-R4 11.00  45.0
group1  R4 group1-R4 22.00  90.0
group1  R4 group1-R4 34.00 128.0
group2  R4 group2-R4  1.00  13.0
group2  R4 group2-R4  5.00  71.0
group2  R4 group2-R4  9.00   NaN
group2  R4 group2-R4 19.00 139.0
group2  R4 group2-R4 31.00 400.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that you are using the `.add_trace` method to plot the average, upper, and lower bounds and calling this method three times. You can condense this down by using the `zip` function to iterate through the different arguments at once for each of the traces at the same time, and therefore you only need to write out .add_trace once.

Personally I consider this harder to read than what you already have and it doesn't do anything different from your code or save time, but it is a bit more succinct (20 lines versus 40 lines)

NOTE: I can't reproduce your exact plot because I believe the data sample you included isn't the full dataset. However, I checked that your original `plot_average_lines` function and my `plot_average_lines` function produce the same plot.

```
def plot_average_lines (df_, name_line ="Group", row=1, col=1):
    name = " " + df_["Group"].iloc[0]
    for bound_type, y_col, marker, line, showlegend, fillcolor, fill in zip(
        ['Average','Upper Bound','Lower Bound'],
        ["y","y_upper","y_lower"],
        [None, dict(color="#444"), dict(color="#444")],
        [dict(color='rgb(31, 119, 180)'), dict(width=0), dict(width=0)],
        [True, False, False],
        [None, None, 'rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.3)'],
        [None, None, 'tonexty']
    ):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            name=bound_type + name ,
            x=df_["x"],
            y=df_[y_col],
            marker=marker,
            line=line,
            mode='lines',
            fillcolor=fillcolor,
            fill=fill,
            showlegend=showlegend, 
            legendgroup=name
        ),
              row=row, col=row)
```

The result is unchanged:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Derek O, as you said i removed a bit of data just so that the idea would be reproducible.  OK so there is no way of doing this with px.scatter(trendline, error bars shaded, grouped by 2 sets), thanks,

Comment: @Leo you could use `px.scatter` but you would still have to add trendlines and shading as separate traces (and adding traces with plotly express is [somewhat inconvenient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122015/how-to-add-traces-in-plotly-express) and probably requires more code than using `go.scatter` for what you are trying to achieve)