# Stack plotly express line chart atop graph_objects filled scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'd like to stack a `plotly.express` line plot atop a filled rectangle from `graph_objects`. Creating the figure with `px.line` and then adding the filled rectangle makes the rectangle show up above the line ([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lsiWErTRNn0ZZVzeg0BwfRqXZ64kT-9S?usp=sharing)).

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = px.line(x=[0, 2, 4], y=[1, 2, 3])
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 1, 3, 3, 1], 
    y=[0, 5, 5, 0, 0],
    fill="toself")
)
fig.show()
```

[image: plot with]

How can I get the line above the rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

Applying the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69318502/1840471) to [How to add traces in plotly.express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62122015/1840471) :

```py
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 1, 3, 3, 1], 
    y=[0, 5, 5, 0, 0],
    fill="toself")
)
fig.add_traces(list(px.line(x=[0, 2, 4], y=[1, 2, 3]).select_traces()))
fig.show()
```

[image]